# Apache2 doesn't give files away

Tags: permissions, apache2

what could it be a reason for such an error:

If I go: http://myhost/munin/

I get **403 Error: Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /munin/ on this server.**

Permissions for files are the following:

```
max@ubuntu:/var/www$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  180 2011-12-28 16:06 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 2011-12-28 08:55 munin
```

ADDITIONAL:

Thank you very much for your help! I did fix it by deleting the dir and targeting munin output html to another dir (actually with the same permissions). I use that apache only for munin, so that strange behavior is ignored.

I did try to access that my numin stats via DNS name. All files in the same www dir were available, also all files in sub/sub/sub/dirs were also available. Only ../munin dir was not working as I expected for some unidentified reason.

Comment: So, I deleted /var/www/munin and pointed munin to another just created folder, now it works. Permissions are exactly the same.. Strange thing. If I create munin folder again - there is no way I can get into it via browser - 403 Error always. This is not my first munin setup, but this case I see for the first time.

Comment: Give us the output of 'ls -la' to see any .htaccess files?

Comment: Also... do a 'tail -f' on the Apache log file for a clue as well?

Comment: And also the url that you used to access it. Are you using 'localhost' or the ip address?.

Comment: if by 'give files' you mean you want a file listing, you might need to add the Indexes override.  in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default either set `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride Indexes` in the DocumentRoot section  (not recommended) or add a new directory config like so.  http://pastebin.com/rsfDiAe4
or if you just want a page loading up you might just need an index.html/index.php file in the folder.  dont forget to restart apache2 `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issues lies on the apache configuration for munin .  As default apache config for munin will allow only the localhost. As you have used http://myhost/munin/. So, we have to modify the apache for the munin to access from all .You can find the default apache config for munin in dir /etc/munin/ as apache.conf .

Look for

```
Allow from localhost 127.0.0.0/8 ::1
```

Change to

```
Allow from all
```

After modifying restart the apache

Comment: I use separately fresh installed Apache2. Is it perfectly working with all other files and sub/sub/diers but /munin. I moved munin output to another dir, so now it is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem.  It turns out that the .htaccess file was not changed when I ran these commands

```
sudo chown -R munin:www-data *
sudo chmod -R g+r *
```

from /var/www/munin.  The '*' file glob excludes 'hidden' files who's name start with '.'

An explicit chown for the .htaccess file

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .htaccess
```

fixed the problem. *(No need to give munin ownership of the .htaccess file.)*

Answer (score 0):

i think munin doesn't have an index.html.

Comment: No,  there was index.html, I did check it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using apache 2.4.10 and munin 2.0.25-1 on ubuntu 15.04

To solve this problem, I followed Lars' sugestion from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127802/munin-server-with-apache-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-munin-on-this-se), i.e. using *Require all granted* instead of *Allow from all*, but applying the changes to the file /etc/munin/apache24.conf

Changing /etc/munin/apache.conf had no effect for me. I have tried to grep me to the file determining which apache config file is chosen without success. But at list I solve the problem.

I hope it can help somebody